# Refresh the method after item add or delete from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, triggers

As in the title, I am developing an application using C# and WPF which acts as a client on many computers and handling a data using SQL within a company. I want it to refresh the views of the items on all computers using this application when one person adds or deletes something from the server's db. I know I might need to use SQL triggers, but I am kind of confused where to start.

just this type of idea:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (trigger1.triggered == true)
          { 
            RefreshView();
            trigger1.triggered == false;
          }
    }
```

Comment: `trigger1.triggered == false;` This line does not make any sense. you probably meant `trigger1.triggered = false;` and does your code not work?

Comment: oh that was just an example. I don't really know how to handle triggers yet

Comment: Do all clients connect directly to the DB ?? or they connect to an application that's connected to DB?

Comment: @T.Aoukar I think OP clearly meant when he said `I am developing an application using C# and WPF which acts as a client on many computers and handling a data using SQL` this.

Comment: I communicate directly with SQL database using queries within a code

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trigger you want.  It's [Query Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Triggers occur when something happens in the database, and allow you to do things like delete related rows in tables without a foreign key to maintain data integrity.  I don't think that they will be of any benefit here because they are intended to do things within the database rather than externally.

The problem with your request and your proposed way of doing it is that it could cause a lot of network traffic.  If you don't have a problem with that, one way would be to use a timestamp.  When the record changes, save the new timestamp in the database.

Now, in your timer on each machine, check to see if the timestamp has changed since the last time you checked. If it has, reload the data.  If not, continue running.

There will be lots of things to think about with this proposition, though.  For example, what if the data on your screen has changed but not been saved when someone else changes it?  Do you lose your changes? Do you list  the changes and ask what to do?  Are you actually entitled to make those changes or does it require administrator approval?

It would be more normal when using Optimistic Locking (last record written is the correct one) to check for a clash at save time rather than polling for the changes.  That way network traffic is reduced but you are told if the record has changed since you loaded it and given the available options on how to proceed.

In the case of lists of records, the simple way to avoid huge network traffic is a simple Refresh button to reload the list.

This article may give you some ideas on ensuring data integrity in multi-user environments: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1178358/What-You-See-Is-What-You-Update

I hope that this gives you some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do is to avoid calling the method on refresh because as #oldcoder said, the network traffic will be unnecessarily big. Just was thinking of something like INSERT from pc1 -> DB -> send information about the insert to pc2,pc3. If this is not possible or too complicating, I will just refresh the function every 10sec or so.